# How to adapt LLaMA v2 model to less than 7B parameters?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I want to pre-train a Decoder (Causal Model) model with less than 7B (since 7B and above are unstable during training, I want to guarantee to the best of my abilities that the pre-training will go smoothly with minimum baby sitting).

Given how nice the pre-training curves for LLaMA v2 (llama2) are I will try that.

What I need is:

1. be able to initialize a llama 2 architecture with less parameters (e.g., decreasing the width or decreasing the layers)
2. then randomly initialize it.

How do I do the above?

Some initial code:

```
    from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, BitsAndBytesConfig, AutoTokenizer
    torch_dtype = torch.bfloat16
    torch_dtype = torch.float32
    pretrained_model_name_or_path = 'meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-hf'
    bf16=torch.cuda.get_device_capability(torch.cuda.current_device())[0] >= 8,  # if >= 8 ==> brain float 16 available or set to True if you always want fp32
    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
        pretrained_model_name_or_path,
        # quantization_config=quantization_config,
        # device_map=device_map,  # device_map = None  https://github.com/huggingface/trl/blob/01c4a35928f41ba25b1d0032a085519b8065c843/examples/scripts/sft_trainer.py#L82
        trust_remote_code=True,
        torch_dtype=torch_dtype,
        use_auth_token=True,
    )
    print(f'{pretrained_model_name_or_path=}')
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model, torch_dtype=torch_dtype, use_auth_token=True)
```

and

```
from llama.models.llama_config import LLaMAConfig

class SmallLlamaConfig(LLaMAConfig):
    hidden_size = 2048
    num_layers = 24

config = SmallLlamaConfig()

model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_config(config,
                                        random_init=True,
                                        load_in=['conv1', 'layer_norm']) 

print(model)
```

note: a different model with the above conditions could work, but llama 2 is the ideal answer I think.

ref so: [How to adapt LLaMA v2 model to less than 7B parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76971761/how-to-get-a-llama-v2-model-with-less-than-7b-parameters)
ref hf: https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/how-to-get-a-llama-v2-model-with-less-than-7b-parameters/52011
ref dis: https://discord.com/channels/879548962464493619/1144325449611235418/1144325449611235418
related: [How does one reinitialize the weights of a Hugging Face LLaMA v2 model the official way as the original model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77499162/how-does-one-reinitialize-the-weights-of-a-hugging-face-llama-v2-model-the-offic)

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77499162/how-does-one-reinitialize-the-weights-of-a-hugging-face-llama-v2-model-the-offic

Answer (score 0):

I think this works. In particular, I use a new config and create a new smaller model and test it by training.

```
import torch
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoConfig 

# Load the pretrained LLaMA v2 config
config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained("meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-hf")

# Print the original number of parameters 
original_model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_config(config) 
print("Original number of parameters:", sum(p.numel() for p in original_model.parameters()))

# Modify the config to reduce size
config.hidden_size = 2048
config.num_hidden_layers = 12

# Create new smaller model from modified config
smaller_model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_config(config)

print("New number of parameters:", sum(p.numel() for p in smaller_model.parameters()))

# You can now train this smaller model 

# Example training loop
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(smaller_model.parameters(), lr=5e-5)  

smaller_model.train() 

for epoch in range(10):
  for input_ids, labels in train_dataloader:
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    outputs = smaller_model(input_ids)  
    loss = outputs.loss
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    
# After training, save the model
smaller_model.save_pretrained("my_smaller_llama")
```