# Does one need to load the model to GPU before calling train when using accelerate?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface, huggingface-trainer

Do I need to call:

```
        device = torch.device(f"cuda:{0}" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
        model = model.to(device)
```

if I am using accelerate? e.g.,

```
accelerate launch --config_file hf_training.py
```

I was worried about the `accelerator.prepare(...)` not working as expected.

related question: [How to adapt LLaMA v2 model to less than 7B parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76971761/how-to-adapt-llama-v2-model-to-less-than-7b-parameters)

the full code of trainer HF: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/v4.33.3/src/transformers/trainer.py#L846

---

## Bounty: Does one need to load the model to GPU before calling train when using accelerate?

The specific issue I am confused is that I want to use normal training single GPU without accelerate and sometimes I do want to use HF + accelerate. In that case is it safe to set the device anyway and then accelerate in HF's trainer will make sure the actual right GPU is set? (I am doing a single server multiple gpus)

---

- related HF discord: https://discord.com/channels/879548962464493619/1169012020721504347/1169012020721504347
- cross: https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/does-one-need-to-load-the-model-to-gpu-before-calling-train-when-using-accelerate/56852

Comment: Does one need to load the model to GPU before calling train when using accelerate?

The specific issue I am confused is that I want to use normal training single GPU without accelerate and sometimes I do want to use HF + accelerate. In that case is it safe to set the device anyway and then accelerate in HF's trainer will make sure the actual right GPU is set? (I am doing a single server multiple gpus)

Comment: So what you want to know is, if you need to take care of the device placement (with accelerate or torch) when you use the hf trainer?

Answer (score 2):

HF always loads your model to GPU if it's available. With accelerate it does it too.

> The Trainer checks torch.cuda.is_available() to detect if GPUs are available.

ref https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/bffac926ca6bc6c965a92bfbfd00c567a2c0fb90/src/transformers/trainer.py#L2298

so

```
       # from accelerate import Accelerator
        # accelerator = Accelerator()
        # # self.is_deepspeed_enabled = getattr(accelerator.state, "deepspeed_plugin", None) is not None
        # is_fsdp_enabled = getattr(accelerator.state, "fsdp_plugin", None) is not None
        # if not is_fsdp_enabled: # not sure if this is needed but its for sure safer
        #     # maybe figuring out how to run everything with accelerate would fix things...
        #     # ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77204403/does-one-need-to-load-the-model-to-gpu-before-calling-train-when-using-accelerat
        #     device = torch.device(f"cuda:{0}" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
        #     model = model.to(device)
```

is not needed. Just load the model and trainer will take care of it.

Comment: Does one need to load the model to GPU before calling train when using accelerate? The specific issue I am confused is that I want to use normal training single GPU without accelerate and sometimes I do want to use HF + accelerate. In that case is it safe to set the device anyway and then accelerate in HF's trainer will make sure the actual right GPU is set? (I am doing a single server multiple gpus)