# How does one reinitialize the weights of a Hugging Face LLaMA v2 model the official way as the original model?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I want to reinitialize the weights of a LLaMA v2 model I'm using/downloading. I went through all the documentation and the source code from their Hugging  Face code:

- https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/models/llama/modeling_llama.py#L721
- https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/modeling_utils.py#L1154
- https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/models/llama/modeling_llama.py#L809
- https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/models/llama/modeling_llama.py#L721
- docs https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/model_doc/llama#transformers.LlamaModel
- and papers where neither of the two mentions how the initialized the models **exactly** or any of the layers llamav1 https://arxiv.org/pdf/2302.13971.pdf and llamav2 https://arxiv.org/pdf/2307.09288.pdf (maybe due to trade secrets?)

I tried the very simple test of going through the modules/parameters and reinitializing according to how their code suggests and printing if the weights norm changed. It never changed, so I don't know if some mutation protection is going on in [PyTorch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyTorch) Hugging  Face models. Is there something I might be doing wrong?

```py
import torch
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoConfig
import torch.nn as nn

def main_reinit_model():
    """
    ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76971761/how-to-adapt-llama-v2-model-to-less-than-7b-parameters
    ref: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/models/llama/modeling_llama.py#L721
    ref: https://chat.openai.com/c/977d0cb0-b819-48ac-be5c-6e482ad5e518
    """
    print('Starting to reinitialize the model...')
    # Load the pretrained LLaMA v2 config
    config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained("meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-hf")
    # print(f'config: {config} {type(config)}')
    # Print the original number of parameters
    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_config(config)
    # put model on device cuda
    model = model.to('cuda')
    # print the model's device
    print(f'{model.device=}')
    # print(f'{model=}')
    # print("Original number of parameters:", sum(p.numel() for p in model.parameters()))
    # go through all parameters and compute the l1 norm and sum it then print it
    norm_model = sum(p.norm(1) for p in model.parameters())
    # loop through modules of model and reinitialize weights with normal_mean, 0.02
    print(f'{norm_model=}')
    """
    go through model and print all laters
    """
    # model.init_weights()  # didn't work
    # model._init_weights(module)  # didn't work needs module
    # for name, param in model.named_parameters():
    #     model._init_weights(param)
    # model.post_init()
    reinitialize_weights(model)
    # model._initialize_weights(module)  # didn't work needs module
    # for name, param in model.named_parameters():
    #     print(f'{name=} {param.shape=}')
    norm_model = sum(p.norm(1) for p in model.parameters())
    print(f'{norm_model=}')

def reinitialize_weights(model) -> None:
    for module in model.modules():
        if isinstance(module, nn.Linear):
            nn.init.normal_(module.weight, mean=0, std=0.02)
            if module.bias is not None:
                nn.init.constant_(module.bias, 0)

def _init_weights(self, module):
    std = self.config.initializer_range
    if isinstance(module, nn.Linear):
        module.weight.data.normal_(mean=100.0, std=std)
        if module.bias is not None:
            module.bias.data.zero_()
    elif isinstance(module, nn.Embedding):
        module.weight.data.normal_(mean=0.0, std=std)
        if module.padding_idx is not None:
            module.weight.data[module.padding_idx].zero_()

def main_generate_smaller_model():
    """
    ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76971761/how-to-adapt-llama-v2-model-to-less-than-7b-parameters
    """
    print('Starting to reinitialize the model...')
    # Load the pretrained LLaMA v2 config
    config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained("meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-hf")
    print(f'config: {config} {type(config)}')
    # Print the original number of parameters
    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_config(config)
    print("Original number of parameters:", sum(p.numel() for p in model.parameters()))

    # Modify the config to reduce size
    config.hidden_size = 2048
    config.num_hidden_layers = 12

    # Create new smaller model from modified config
    smaller_model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_config(config)
    print("New number of parameters:", sum(p.numel() for p in smaller_model.parameters()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time
    start = time.time()
    # main_generate_smaller_model()
    main_reinit_model()
    print('Done!\a\a\a')
```

And the output never showed the weight norms changed:

```
Starting to reinitialize the model...
model.device=device(type='cuda', index=0)
norm_model=tensor(1.0779e+08, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)
norm_model=tensor(1.0779e+08, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)
Done!
```

What am I doing wrong? I need to know how to reinitialize the weights in the **proper/correct way** according to LLaMA. What exact init method and values should I use?

---

Related

- related blog: https://blog.briankitano.com/llama-from-scratch/
- Hugging Face question pre-train: https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/can-i-pretrain-llama-from-scratch/37821/7
- Hugging Face Discord: https://discord.com/channels/879548962464493619/1174911090254172231/1174911090254172231
- Hugging Face question reinit: https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/how-does-one-reinitialize-the-weights-of-a-hugging-face-llama-v2-model-the-official-way-as-the-original-model/62547
- related: [How to adapt LLaMA v2 model to less than 7B parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76971761/how-to-adapt-llama-v2-model-to-less-than-7b-parameters)

Comment: Your question is, as one of your previous [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77204403/does-one-need-to-load-the-model-to-gpu-before-calling-train-when-using-accelerat/77204448#77204448), nearly unreadable. 50% of your code snippet are just notes that are unrelated to the question. You also raise two different questions. The title indicates you are looking for the original initialization parameters while your question text wants to know if you made a mistake with reinitializing the model. Please edit your question to make it clear what you want to know.

Comment: [The bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77499162/timeline) may attract [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) plagiarisers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [Huggingface Course](https://huggingface.co/learn/nlp-course/chapter7/6) helps. There the provide an example how to instantiate GPT2 from a pre-trained config.

The important piece of code is this:

```
config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(
    "gpt2", # change this to "meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-hf"
    vocab_size=len(tokenizer),
    n_ctx=context_length,
    bos_token_id=tokenizer.bos_token_id,
    eos_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id,
    trust_remote_code=True # maybe you need this
    use_auth_token=True # you will need this for LLaMA2 (it is a gated model)
)
```

I think this will intantiate a new model with same specs as the original LlaMA2.
EDIT:
You need to use huggingface_hub to [login](https://huggingface.co/docs/huggingface_hub/v0.19.0.rc0/en/package_reference/login), maybe have a look into [Quickstart](https://huggingface.co/docs/huggingface_hub/quick-start).

Additional References:

[Huggingface Docs AutoClasses](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.14.1/model_doc/auto)

[Huggingface Docs AutoConfig](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.36.1/en/model_doc/auto#transformers.AutoConfig)

Answer (score -1):

try with this example

```
import torch
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoConfig
import torch.nn as nn

def main_reinit_model():
    print('Starting to reinitialize the model...')
    
    # Load the pretrained LLaMA v2 config
    config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained("meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-hf")
    
    # Print the original number of parameters
    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_config(config)
    
    # Reinitialize weights
    reinitialize_weights(model)
    
    # Move the model to GPU (cuda) after initializing weights
    model = model.to('cuda')
    
    # Print the model's device
    print(f'{model.device=}')
    
    # Print the original number of parameters
    print("Original number of parameters:", sum(p.numel() for p in model.parameters()))

    # Print the model architecture
    print(model)

def reinitialize_weights(model) -> None:
    for module in model.modules():
        if isinstance(module, nn.Linear):
            nn.init.normal_(module.weight, mean=0, std=0.02)
            if module.bias is not None:
                nn.init.constant_(module.bias, 0)

def main_generate_smaller_model():
    """
    ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76971761/how-to-adapt-llama-v2-model-to-less-than-7b-parameters
    """
    print('Starting to generate a smaller model...')
    # Load the pretrained LLaMA v2 config
    config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained("meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-hf")
    print(f'config: {config} {type(config)}')
    # Print the original number of parameters 
    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_config(config) 
    print("Original number of parameters:", sum(p.numel() for p in model.parameters()))

    # Modify the config to reduce size
    config.hidden_size = 2048
    config.num_hidden_layers = 12

    # Create a new smaller model from the modified config
    smaller_model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_config(config)
    print("New number of parameters:", sum(p.numel() for p in smaller_model.parameters()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time
    start = time.time()
    # main_generate_smaller_model() 
    main_reinit_model()
    print('Done!\a\a\a')
```

I see a possible problem in the main_reinit_model function. Specifically, you are trying to move the model to the `GPU (cuda)` before initializing the weights.