# How to put hugging face model (e.g., smaller llama2) on bfloat 16 using the config?

Tags: huggingface

Since I need a smaller model I need to use the config. But putting bfloat16n in the config didn't work e.g.,

```py
def get_smaller_llama2(hidden_size : int = 2048, 
                       num_hidden_layers : int = 12, 
                       return_tokenizer: bool = False, 
                       verbose : bool = False,
                       ):
    config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained("meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-hf")
    config.hidden_size = hidden_size
    config.num_hidden_layers = num_hidden_layers
    smaller_model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_config(config)
    # NOTE: putting torch_dtype in the config doesn't work, so you have to move the model to bfloat16 later with model.to(torch.bfloat16)
    config.torch_dtype = torch.bfloat16 if torch.cuda.get_device_capability(torch.cuda.current_device())[0] >= 8 else torch.float32 # if >= 8 ==> brain float 16 available or set to True if you always want fp32
    device = torch.device(f"cuda:{0}" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    smaller_model = smaller_model.to(device)
    # smaller_model = smaller_model.to(torch_dtype) # does work!
    print(f'Model is currently on: {next(iter(smaller_model.parameters())).dtype=}')
    if verbose:
        print(f'config: {config}')
        print("Smaller number of parameters:", sum(p.numel() for p in smaller_model.parameters()))
        print(f'Model is currently on: {next(iter(smaller_model.parameters())).device=}')
        print(f'Model is currently on: {next(iter(smaller_model.parameters())).dtype=}')
        print()
    if return_tokenizer:
        tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-hf', padding_side="right", use_fast=False, trust_remote_code=True, use_auth_token=True)
        return smaller_model, tokenizer
    return smaller_model
```

how to fix?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77499162/how-does-one-reinitialize-the-weights-of-a-hugging-face-llama-v2-model-the-offic

Answer (score 0):

To fix this you need to explicitly move it there idk why putting it the config doesn't work:

```py
model.to(torch.bfloat16)
```